# How to create a Custom Dialog box in android with library or class?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to create a custom dialog box like below

[image]

I need a dialog box with the following features

1. The right header text can be changed
2. The left header image can be changed
3. The header background color and height can be changed
4. content text & text color and background color can be changed
   And finally the Button text and color can be changed

It does not matter whether it's a library or a Java class
If you have a library with these features Please introduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the `DialogFragment Class` in android to build customized dialogs the right way.

> A fragment that displays a dialog window, floating on top of its activity's window. This fragment contains a Dialog object, which it displays as appropriate based on the fragment's state. Control of the dialog (deciding when to show, hide, dismiss it) should be done through the API here, not with direct calls on the dialog.

Implementations should override this class and implement onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) to supply the content of the dialog. Alternatively, they can override onCreateDialog(Bundle) to create an entirely custom dialog, such as an AlertDialog, with its own content. [Source -](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Comment: Dialog fragments is a big topic in itself, the official documentation contains all the information you need.

Comment: That is a good idea, I searched for it I think I meet my needs,But I am a beginner
And I can not design fragment xml  layout I'm trying to see what happens

Comment: What exactly are you asking for design implementation or ?

Comment: I found a good tutorial about it,  http://www.appa2z.com/2014/10/android-custom-dialog-fragment.html

Comment: Something like in my question image

Comment: Thats a standard design, have you seen AlertDialogs?, it as built in designs to accommodate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new activity with dialog theme. There you have all freedom to design as you have layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular Android dialog with a custom layout. To do so, create an xml file with your desired layout, then use a `LayoutInflater` with `Dialog` to show it. [Reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout).

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is how I do it (my way)

```
public class ReconnectDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private final static String TAG = ReconnectDialog.class.getSimpleName();

    Dialog dialog;

    public ReconnectDialog(){
        // can be custom
    }

    public void show(){
        dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.reconnect_dialog);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);


    dialog.show();
    }

    public void dismiss(){
        if (dialog != null)
            dialog.dismiss();
        else
            Log.i(TAG, "dialog is null...");
    }

    public boolean isDismissed(){
        return dialog != null && !dialog.isShowing();
    }
}
```